# Adobe Air - Change app window meta title

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

Is it possible to change the **meta title** text that is display in an Adobe Air desktop app header? (Where by default is the **app name** displayed)

Thanks.
Uli

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure:

```
protected function initWindowName(event:Event):void 
{
    stage.nativeWindow.title = "new name";
}
```

And listen to an event such as:

```
addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, initWindowName);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change it at runtime follow davivid's answer. This is useful if you want to update the header to display the current file name the user is working with or something like that.

If you want to set the title once and not change it, or set a default, change the [title](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f2fea1812938a6e463-8000.html#WSfffb011ac560372f2fea1812938a6e463-7ff3) tag in the application descriptor xml.